# Documentation on how to create Debian init.d scripts

Tags: linux, debian

I'm looking for some documentation/tutorial on how to create good init.d scripts for different services in Debian.
This article is nice introduction: http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/28 but I'm looking for more details.
Thanks!

Comment: Not very detailed but the debian policy manual has a section on what a "good" init script should contain. http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-opersys.html#s-sysvinit

Comment: @topdog this is nice, can you move you comment to an answer, so I could accept it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not very detailed but the debian policy manual has a section on what a "good" init script should contain. http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-opersys.html#s-sysvinit